# Probability of arrangements that starts with an alpha run of length $ l \geq 0$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is a question from Feller's probability text book volume 1. Show that the probability that an arrangements of $r_1$ alphas and $r_2$ betas (alphas and betas are indistinguishable) such that the arrangement contains exactly $k$ runs of either kind and starts with an alpha run of length $ l \geq 0$ is

$$
(r_1)_l r_2/(r_1+r_2)_{l+1}
$$

Here $k = 2*l+1$ or $k = 2*l$

A [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3637566/find-the-probability-that-the-arrangement-starts-with-an-alpha-run-of-length-v) is already asked here. But there is no solution given there.

Comment: You have mis-quoted the exercise in Feller.  He has $\nu$ where you have $k$. Changing variable names is not a serious mistake, but  looking at the exercise in the text, I think you have mistakenly combined it with the previous exercise.  I don't think this exercise has anything to do with $k$ runs. $\nu$ is simply the length of the initial run of alphas.

Comment: I think the problem should simply be this: You have $r_1$ alphas and $r_2$ betas, find the probability that the string has an initial run of (exactly} $\nu$ alphas.